# How to send POST request with Dev HTTP Client

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I use [Dev Http Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) for testing REST API. I can't figure out how can I send POST requests. Whatever parameters or query String that I put in body does not show up in request parameters in chrome developer console.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the developers for Dev Http Client. As far as I can see, there is a bug, but it is only a problem with Chrome Dev Tools itself, for some reason request body isn't displayed. I've tried with multiple APIs and multiple sites, requests are actually sent, but DevTools simply doesn't display them.

You can check it by yourself via [postcatcher](http://postcatcher.in) , it will give you and URL where you can direct post requests, and if you keep this url opened in browser, it will show you all the post requests you've send (including their bodies).

Comment: Thanks, but I could see request body sent by another chrome extensions Advanced REST client

Comment: Well I'm aware of that, we can fix this on our side, but I'll report this to Chrome team as well, because it is also bug in Dev Tools (you can't see body if it is blob type, and Dev Http Client wraps all requests with bodies into blobs). Anyway POST requests are working in dev http client

Comment: Already? Thanks. Also you can share the chromium bug number if you would like for future readers.

Comment: I seem to struggle to issue POST request with body... Are you sure this has been fixed?

Comment: My fault, I was missing ```app.use(express.bodyParser());``` in my node app. Having said that - http://i.imgur.com/MXJVzkR.png - sadly there is no post data in Chrome Dev Tools :(